# Strange error while running Win Forms project

Tags: visual-studio-2012

I have a solution with multiple projects.
One project is a windows Forms project & the others are Class Library Projects.
I have set the win forms project as the start-up project.
When I right click the win form project then select "Debug" then "Start new instance", sometimes I am getting this error:

> A project with an Output Type of Class Library cannot be started
>   directly. In order to debug this project, add an executable project to
>   this solution which references the library project. Set the executable
>   project as the start-up project.

I noticed that almost each time VS2012 loses focus ( because I clicked on another window ) during the build process, I will get this error!!
Any idea what could be the issue?

UPDATE:
I noticed that during the build, it is enough to change the selected project to any other project to cause this error!!

Comment: Hmm, that's pretty bizarre.  Start pressing the F5 key instead, like everyone does.

Comment: I have multiple win forms projects in my solution that I need to run to test out different functionality of our code.

Comment: I have filed a bug with Microsoft : [link](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/771033/error-while-trying-to-run-windows-forms-application)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that this a bug that Microsoft confirmed on this link:

[Error while trying to run Windows Forms Application](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/771033/error-while-trying-to-run-windows-forms-application)

This bug is a duplicate of the following bug:

[Wrong project started](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/765864/wrong-project-started)

Microsoft will not address the fix for this bug for VS 2012.